# When in Rome, Count as Romans do?

Tags: code-golf, roman-numerals

## Background

This challenge is inspired by [this](http://datagenetics.com/blog/april22013/index.html) website, which published the following diagram:

[image]

This diagram shows us that the longest Roman Numeral expression under 250 is that of 188, which requires 9 numerals to express.

## Challenge

The standard symbols used to express most Roman Numerals are the following: {`I`, `V`, `X`, `L`, `C`, `D`, `M`}, where the characters' numeric values are `M`=1000, `D`=500, `C`=100, `L`=50, `X`=10, `V`=5, `I`=1.

In this challenge, your goal is to, given an positive integer *n*, compute the number of valid Roman Numeral representations that can be composed through concatenating *n* of the standard symbols.

Then, your program must output the result of this computation!

**Input**: A positive integer *n*.

**Output**: The number of valid roman numeral expressions of length *n*.

## Rules for Roman Numeral Expressions

Roman Numerals originally only had "additive" pairing, meaning that numerals were always written in descending order, and the sum of the values of all the numerals was the value of the number.

Later on, subtractive pairing, the use of placing a smaller numeral in front of a larger in order to subtract the smaller from the larger, became commonplace to shorten Roman Numeral expressions. Subtractive pairs cannot be chained, like in the following invalid expression: `IXL`.

The following are the modern day rules for additive and subtractive pairing.

1. Only one I, X, and C can be used as the leading numeral in part of a subtractive pair.
2. I can only be placed before V or X in a subtractive pair.
3. X can only be placed before L or C in a subtractive pair.
4. C can only be placed before D or M in a subtractive pair.
5. Other than subtractive pairs, numerals must be in descending order (meaning that if you drop the leading numeral of each subtractive pair, then the numerals will be in descending order).
6. M, C, and X cannot be equalled or exceeded by smaller denominations.
7. D, L, and V can each only appear once.
8. Only M can be repeated 4 or more times.

## Further Notes

- We will not be using the *bar* notation; rather, we will simply add more *M*s to express any number.
- These are the **only** rules that we will follow for our roman numerals. That means that odd expressions, such as `IVI`, will also be considered valid in our system.
- Also remember that we are not counting the number of numbers that have expressions of length *n*, since some numbers have multiple expressions. Instead, we are solely counting the number of valid expressions.

## Test Cases

`1` → `7`

`2` → `31`

`3` → `105`

I checked the above by hand, so please make sure to double check the test cases, and add more if you can!

## Winning Criteria

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge, so have fun! I will only accept solutions that can handle at least inputs from 1 through 9. Any more is bonus!

## Edit

As requested by commenters, find below, or at this pastebin link, the 105 combos I counted for *n*=3

> III
>   IVI
>   IXI
>   IXV
>   IXX
>   VII
>   XII
>   XIV
>   XIX
>   XVI
>   XXI
>   XXV
>   XXX
>   XLI
>   XLV
>   XLX
>   XCI
>   XCV
>   XCX
>   XCL
>   XCC
>   LII
>   LIV
>   LIX
>   LVI
>   LXI
>   LXV
>   LXX
>   CII
>   CIV
>   CIX
>   CVI
>   CXI
>   CXV
>   CXX
>   CXL
>   CXC
>   CLI
>   CLV
>   CLX
>   CCI
>   CCV
>   CCX
>   CCL
>   CCC
>   CDI
>   CDV
>   CDX
>   CDL
>   CDC
>   CMI
>   CMV
>   CMX
>   CML
>   CMC
>   CMD
>   CMM
>   DII
>   DIV
>   DIX
>   DVI
>   DXI
>   DXV
>   DXX
>   DXL
>   DXC
>   DLI
>   DLV
>   DLX
>   DCI
>   DCV
>   DCX
>   DCL
>   DCC
>   MII
>   MIV
>   MIX
>   MVI
>   MXI
>   MXV
>   MXX
>   MXL
>   MXC
>   MLI
>   MLV
>   MLX
>   MCI
>   MCV
>   MCX
>   MCL
>   MCC
>   MCD
>   MCM
>   MDI
>   MDV
>   MDX
>   MDL
>   MDC
>   MMI
>   MMV
>   MMX
>   MML
>   MMC
>   MMD
>   MMM

## Edit 2:

Use the following non-golfed [code](https://tio.run/##jVPRatswFH2evuIuUCxjJ@BubGBwH5a0EEgIZJkJtHlQbKXVsCUjy6PZz6eSrLieS5vpQfjK59x77rlSdVRPgl@fTgcpSmCKSiVEUQMrKyEVVFLkTaYQyukBJNXf9FdVUTklNV2LknCs6LPyYwR6HYQExnP6HAImIex9HQHlTUklURT/ZZVFh2D2@yje@Y5oFjsACfaGgb156oXgzbdm3y7sPjX7dGb3pdfjmSWpaiRv08ZWwQ6CNrRREJn4XfkOdK0FoUE61Hb@hxQs1z2837uRz4/2ZJKJhiuc@XADkTUlM22NZot05IMOuVBAigK3x/N0u5jOlqNXZC9tT84dKWrq9JlG8o2GQfLBVCy4tb@Y85xljNaacN@VnNjGjdKudi/37tzYWS@BmwT2FmvGa@BmpoMK4bDkedKf3jTiTBvi2Q4@J/BN/8uhoBzXVL3FxCz4qtNCkjiTmZVP@CPFhjQg@DCGL/7HrtqDjWyom7p5DamZ/MBcnf5RPfUuvatVGwXuxeDO5FBnrihRyT80s1Q7QM@b/BasU1z7/Tdx@ead15HRIneX9m69WoawWensUQjfETIq2/qvLnWgACKXq5KMKwcMoW5K3HprlWriBUd8hNLb9Y/Vz1td2BqpO3An/QLeAx@Pxw/c6xz8D209@lUde3DlSMOf4Oy8qHXA89Dp9AI), as courtesy of Jonathan Allan to check your results.

## Edit 3:

I apologize for all of the errors in this challenge. I'll make sure to do a better job next time!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81491/discussion-on-question-by-rushabh-mehta-when-in-rome-count-as-romans-do).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 111 bytes

```
~(`.+
*$(CM)CDXCXCXCXLIXIXIXIVII
.(.)
.+¶$$&$¶$$&$1$¶$$&$&¶L`.{0,$+}\b¶D`¶
¶$
¶.+¶$$&$¶$$&I¶L`[A-Z]{$+}\b¶D`¶.+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/v04jQU@bS0tFw9lX09klwhkMfTwjwDDM05NLT0NPk0tP@9A2FRU1FQhpCKXVDm3zSdCrNtBR0a6NSTq0zSXh0DYuoBQQo2jwBKmLdtSNiq1GUqmn/f@/MQA) This is a complete rewrite as I misunderstood rule 1. to mean that you could only use one each of subtractive `I`, `X` and `C`. Explanation: The first part of the script expands the input into a string of `CM` pairs followed by the other possible subtractive pairs. Each pair is optional, and the first character of each pair is also optional within the pair. The third stage then expands the list of pairs into a list of Retina commands that take the input and create three copies with the option of the second or both characters from the pair, then trims and deduplicates the results. The final stage then appends code to perform the final tasks: first to expand the input to possibly add a final `I`, then to filter out results of the wrong length, then to deduplicate the results, and finally to count the results. The resulting Retina script is then evaluated.

Note: In theory 15 bytes could be saved from the end of the 4th line but this makes the script too slow to demonstrate on TIO even for `n=1`.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Ah, then you're including multiple subtractive pairs with the same leading numeral, which is wrong.

Comment: @JonathanAllan New rewrite, coincidentally for the exact same byte count!

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>177 168</s> 162 bytes

```python
import re,itertools as q
f=lambda n:sum(None!=re.match("^M*(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})$",(''.join(m)))for m in q.product('MDCLXVI',repeat=n))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcrLisIwFADQ9fgV1yL0RkLRcSeULtJNoXVZshKiTccMzcPbuBgmfntFZpYHTviJN@8@l8XY4CkCaW6ipuj9NIOa4b4ay0nZy6DAHeeHxZN3el2SLqyK1xtm526LokuiTnUlfnf88GQoRZJtaiv570ampk991fx5k3HM8@LbG4eWMTZ6AgvGwb0I5IfHNWLe1aKVfZNz0kGrWDrGlvcz70fKfWnAPd/v2HH1Eci4CCMatrwA)

I'm pretty new, help me golf this! This checks for actual roman numerals, the regex needs to be adjusted to account for the odd cases such as `IVI`

**-9 bytes** thanks to @Dead Possum!

**-6 bytes** thanks to @ovs

Comment: Yeah I think the n=3 case might be wrong in the example. I was originally getting 93 with `^M*(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})$`

Comment: [171 bytes](https://tio.run/##Jc0xC8IwEAXg2f6KKELvahEUXISSIV0K1VE6CVFTjZhcuMbBX19Tnd4H78ELn/ggvx1H6wJxFGyynskJGw1Hotcg/kWR9dVLu8tNC78f3g6O5M28YrN2Ol4fsDiDkocVSgBVS5T1pE4lqZ/apDapkd3qF6cUTbFclJDn6ydZDw4Re2KRzr0ITLf3NUJ@qFXbnZq8ZBOMjpVHHKeVnVas/d0I2JQ73GezwNZH0YPF8Qs)

Comment: FWIW your numbers aggree with http://oeis.org/A199921 ...it has a(4)=215, but `MMMM` would make that 216 :)

Comment: @JonathanAllan Good to know :) Thanks!

Comment: Now we have a list of the n=3 values considered correct by the OP I believe the shortfall is the lack of some of the noted "odd expressions" like "IVI".

Comment: @JonathanAllan I would be willing to adjust the rules if that made the answer easier/more consistent.

Comment: @RushabhMehta - that is totally up to you, your definitions are, I believe, workable (and interesting to code for) even if they do produce what we now consider "invalid" Roman numerals, back then they may have been used? (I'm no expert)

Comment: @JonathanAllan I spent around two days asking around on Math stackexchange trying to make sure these rules made sense. Guess I didn't do enough :(

Comment: @RushabhMehta This is a very well formatted challenge and fun to program, don't feel bad about an unfortunate nuance in nitty-gritty of roman numeral definition. It is your challenge, specify it as you see fit. it is workable in the other sense, just more difficult

Comment: This doesn't seem to give the right answer for 3. `93` instead of `105`

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES7), 133 bytes

***Edit**: Fixed to match the results returned by [Jonathan Allan's code](https://tio.run/##jVPRatswFH2evuIuUCxjJ@BubGBwH5a0EEgIZJkJtHlQbKXVsCUjy6PZz6eSrLieS5vpQfjK59x77rlSdVRPgl@fTgcpSmCKSiVEUQMrKyEVVFLkTaYQyukBJNXf9FdVUTklNV2LknCs6LPyYwR6HYQExnP6HAImIex9HQHlTUklURT/ZZVFh2D2@yje@Y5oFjsACfaGgb156oXgzbdm3y7sPjX7dGb3pdfjmSWpaiRv08ZWwQ6CNrRREJn4XfkOdK0FoUE61Hb@hxQs1z2837uRz4/2ZJKJhiuc@XADkTUlM22NZot05IMOuVBAigK3x/N0u5jOlqNXZC9tT84dKWrq9JlG8o2GQfLBVCy4tb@Y85xljNaacN@VnNjGjdKudi/37tzYWS@BmwT2FmvGa@BmpoMK4bDkedKf3jTiTBvi2Q4@J/BN/8uhoBzXVL3FxCz4qtNCkjiTmZVP@CPFhjQg@DCGL/7HrtqDjWyom7p5DamZ/MBcnf5RPfUuvatVGwXuxeDO5FBnrihRyT80s1Q7QM@b/BasU1z7/Tdx@ead15HRIneX9m69WoawWensUQjfETIq2/qvLnWgACKXq5KMKwcMoW5K3HprlWriBUd8hNLb9Y/Vz1td2BqpO3An/QLeAx@Pxw/c6xz8D209@lUde3DlSMOf4Oy8qHXA89Dp9AI), which was given as a reference implementation by the OP.*

---

```javascript
n=>[...Array(m=k=7**n)].reduce(s=>s+/^1*5?4{0,3}3?2{0,3}6?0{0,3}$/.test((--k+m).toString(7).replace(/0[62]|2[34]|4[51]/g,s=>s[1])),0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HczNisIwGIXhvVfxLYTJ1zTprzowkxavwWWIUGpaHGsiSUYQ9dprdHOezeH9666d793xEpixBz0PYjaikZzzrXPdjZzFSWySxKDiTh/@e028aDzN9kWyaut7nlbPqi0/rtv84zLjQftACGMnekYe7C64oxnJBmPjMnUxkuVyXapHKataPWq5KlQ2pu@yLBRimuM8WEcMCCh@wMAvfEcoRbgvAHprvJ00n@wYLxS@gLEmLoWBGMTFc34B)

#### How?

1) We generate all numbers of \$N\$ digits in base 7 with an extra leading \$1\$:

```
[...Array(m = k = 7 ** n)].reduce(s => … (--k + m).toString(7) …, 0)
```

From now on, each digit will be interpreted as a Roman numeral symbol:

$$\begin{array}{}0\longleftrightarrow \text{I}, & 1\longleftrightarrow \text{M}, & 2\longleftrightarrow \text{X}, & 3\longleftrightarrow \text{L},\\
4\longleftrightarrow \text{C}, & 5\longleftrightarrow \text{D}, & 6\longleftrightarrow \text{V}
\end{array}$$

2) We replace all valid subtractive pairs of the form `AB` with `B`:

```javascript
.replace(/0[62]|2[34]|4[51]/g, s => s[1]))  // in the code
.replace(/I[VX]|X[LC]|C[DM]/g, s => s[1]))  // with Roman symbols
```

**Examples:**

- `XLIXIV` becomes `LXV`
- `XIIV` becomes `XIV`, leaving a `I` that will make the next test fail
- `IC` remains unchanged, which also leaves an invalid `I` in place

3) We check that the remaining symbols are in the correct order and do not appear more times than they're allowed to:

```javascript
/^1*5?4{0,3}3?2{0,3}6?0{0,3}$/.test(…)  // in the code
/^M*D?C{0,3}L?X{0,3}V?I{0,3}$/.test(…)  // with Roman symbols
```

Comment: Holy cow, I didn't expect this one to be done in less than 200 bytes in non esoteric languages! Mind explaining how this works?

Comment: However, I have noticed that this doesn't work for *n*>4 on TIO, which is somewhat unfortunate.

Comment: @RushabhMehta I've added a non-recursive version to test higher values. I'll add an explanation when I'm done golfing this.

Answer (score 0):

## C, <strike>150</strike> 123 bytes

I didn't read the description closely enough, so this produces the number of standard Roman numerals (where expressions like `IVI` aren't counted). Since I put some effort into it, I thought I would share anyway.

```
#define F(X) for(X=10;X--;)
x[]={0,1,2,3,2,1,2,3,4,2};f(i,o,a,b,c){for(i++;i--;)F(a)F(b)F(c)o+=i==x[a]+x[b]+x[c];return o;}
```

Original (150 bytes):

```
#define F(X) for(X=10;X--;)
i,o,a,b,c,x[]={0,1,2,3,2,1,2,3,4,2};main(){scanf("%i",&i);for(i++;i--;)F(a)F(b)F(c)o+=i==x[a]+x[b]+x[c];printf("%i\n",o);}
```

Comment: You're only allowed to post valid submissions.

Comment: @CurtisBechtel You can keep the solution here I suppose, but I would try to modify it to satisfy the rules of the challenge.

Comment: I think you can remove the space between `F(X)` and `for(X=10;X--;)`